# Making Security Component work in CakePHP

Tags: php, html, css, cakephp

Here's my situation. I've heard that the `requireAuth()` function of `Security` component generates a new key for every form once the page is reloaded. But i've tried it in every single controller in my application by using the below code

```
function beforeFilter()
{
...
$this->Security->requireAuth();
}
```

But still none of the forms in my application generates the key. I've even submitted the form, still the key remains the same. My `Security.level` is set to `high` in `core.php`

Comment: `requireAuth` has nothing to do with forms. Are you using the FormHelper to create forms? Also, are you sure you're looking for the right thing?

Comment: @deceze i'm using form helper for forms. I can see the key value. but it's always the same for every form. And im looking for the ri8 thing.

Comment: Are you talking about `<input type="hidden" name="data[_Token][key]" value="3fb..." id="Token103...">`?

Answer (score 1):

**Edited answer**

Looking at the source code for the FormHelper, as far as the token being the same, if `$this->params['_Token']` is set, it uses `$this->params['_Token']['key']` as the hidden fields value. The hidden fields `id` on the other hand is randomly generated not the token key.

When using the `$this->Form->end()` method, if `$this->params['_Token']` is set, the fields are run through a method called `secure()`. This essentially serializes the form fields and runs them through `Security::hash()` which creates an SHA1 hash of the serialized fields. If the form has been tampered with this hash will be different from the original token, thus Cake knows the form has been tampered with.

`$this->Security->requireAuth()` has nothing to do with your forms it sets the action to require SSL.

Comment: i didn't get the SSL part. Could u ellaborate the use of requireAuth()